# Porque "meu programa" não incrementou o valor 5 sendo que ele menor que 5.5

Tags: java

Estou começando na programação e sempre tento desvendar as coisas que não ficam claras, até agora consegui, mas nesse aqui ja tentei e tentei e não conseguir entender porque o programa não incrementou o valor 5 sendo que ele menor que 5.5

```
public class Primo {
public static boolean ehPrimo(float nr) {
    if (nr < 2)
        return false;
    for (float i = 2; i <= (nr / 2); i++) {
        if (nr % i == 0)
        return false;
        System.out.println("nr = " + nr + "\ti = " +i);
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float x = 11f;
    if (ehPrimo(x)) // se for primo
        System.out.println(x + " e primo");
    else // se não for primo
        System.out.println(x + " não e primo");
}
}
```

Comment: Incrementou onde? Não entendi a origem do problema no código.

Comment: O codigo esta ok, só estou tentando entende-lo melhor.

Em um etapa do loop o 'i' está valendo '5' e 'nr' '11' 

( nr / 2 ) é igual a 5.5 

No caso quando 'i' for <= a 5.5 ele deveria incrementar o 'i' tornando ele '6' e ai quando ele fosse verificar se 'i' agora '6' não era <= 5.5 ele pararia o loop, mas o loop para o com 'i' valendo '5' sendo que é 5 <= 5.5 condição na qual ele deveria continuar o loop.

Obrigado pela atenção, deculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Não, o loop para em 6.0, pois 6.0 é maior que 5.5. Por isso não entra mais no loop e não exibe o System.out.println. Tanto que a última saída exibida é nr = 11.0 i = 5.0, pois foi a última vez que entrou no loop. Pelo menos foi esse o resultado no [ideone](https://ideone.com/ArJRLk)

Comment: Porque `float` e não `int`? Está a trabalhar com números inteiros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dúvida ficou meio no ar, mas pelo que entendi você quer saber o motivo pelo qual o for não deu mais um ciclo.

O for no seu código quando inserimos o valor 11 faz o seguinte:

- Valor inicial: 2.0    Valor quando acaba o ciclo: 3.0
- Valor inicial: 3.0    Valor quando acaba o ciclo: 4.0
- Valor inicial: 4.0    Valor quando acaba o ciclo: 5.0
- Valor inicial: 5.0    Valor quando acaba o ciclo: 6.0

Então no final do ultimo ciclo ele já é maior que 6 por isso ele não incrementa novamente.

```
for (float i = 2; i <= (numero / 2); i++) { //conteúdo do for... }
```

1. inicia-se a variável
2. verifica a condição: i <= (numero /2)
3. roda todo o conteúdo do for
4. realiza a pós-condição: i++

O for inicia a variável e depois fica no ciclo até que a condição não seja mais válida.

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos hehe